# Book Recommendation: Training

Tags: training, book

I am curious if anyone has any interesting books (preferred) or blogs on training for cycling.

Right now I ride for a couple hours twice a week, I have a short 15 min commute to work and I ride for half a day every weekend.  I just moved to a new city so I am mostly riding by myself but I want to improve my speed, distance and fitness.

I was hoping that someone could suggest me a good book about cycling training.

Comment: This question really has no single, correct answer. Yeah, it's an old question, but have voted to close.

Answer (score 8):

[image: cover]

It should be "The Cyclist's Training Bible: A Complete Training Guide for the Competitive Road Cyclist" by Joe Friel.

It is considered one of the best books about cycling training, even if you are a mountain biker - endurance training needs to happen on road as you need to maintain reasonable heart rate for lots of training types.

The book has been published several times, the most recent edition in June 18, 2009

After reading it, you can also read [Friels blog](http://www.joefrielsblog.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I like [Base Building for Cyclists](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?rlz=1C1SKPL_enUS424US424&q=base%20building%20for%20cyclists&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=shop&cid=5277244778263260522&sa=X&ei=dlGXTsnbNqzRiAKSk4yxAg&ved=0CFwQ8gIwAw) as a good guide to building your aerobic fitness, building a solid base for seasonal training, and working up to high volume rides.

[image]

I also like [The Heart Rate Monitor Book for Cyclists](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=heart%20rate%20book%20for&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=shop&cid=14339288673626865424&sa=X&ei=XVKXTv7wEsnjiAKxl-inDQ&ved=0CHoQ8wIwAg) for cycling specific workouts to improve speed and aerobic threshold.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have been training with this book myself and have found it invaluable. It is easy to read and full of tried and tested training and nutritional advice.

[image: Serious cycling by E R. Burke]

With regards to blogs this is a post I have found useful [Rapha Winter Training](http://www.rapha.cc/winter-training)  there are other interesting posts on the site.

Some good information can be found on the Peloton magazine site [Peloton - Training Part 1](http://www.pelotonmagazine.com/Wisdom/content/19/947/Training-Part-I)